# STM32 USB problem: IN-endpoint sends nothing to host

Tags: usb, stm32

I need to program a custom USB device based on STM32F107 so that it has two identical USB interfaces, each interface has a pair of bulk endpoints (OUT/IN).
I generated a project with a virtual COM port (CDC) via STM32CubeMX - everything works. I started modifying it for my task:

1. Modified USB descriptors: I created one configuration with two interfaces, each with a pair of bulk endpoints (OUT/IN) with addresses 0x01/0x81 and 0x02/0x82.
2. In the `USBD_LL_Init function`, I increased the number of endpoints from 4 to 6:

```
    hpcd_USB_OTG_FS.Init.dev_endpoints = 6; // 00/80 - zero-endpoint + 4 of my points
```

and added one TX fifo for IN point 0x82:

```
    HAL_PCDEx_SetRxFiFo(&hpcd_USB_OTG_FS, 0x80);
    HAL_PCDEx_SetTxFiFo(&hpcd_USB_OTG_FS, 0, 0x40);
    HAL_PCDEx_SetTxFiFo(&hpcd_USB_OTG_FS, 1, 0x80);
    HAL_PCDEx_SetTxFiFo(&hpcd_USB_OTG_FS, 2, 0x80); // I added this
```

3. In the `USBD_CDC_Init` function, I added the initialization of points 0x02/0x82 (using the `USBD_LL_OpenEP` function), by analogy with the initialization of points 0x01/0x81 already there.
4. To the `CDC_Receive_FS` function (callback on data receiving to OUT endpoint) I added "echo" code: I sent the same data to the IN point.
5. When the device was connected to the computer, a composite USB device appeared in the Windows Device Manager in the form of two (according to the number of interfaces) sub-devices, for which, as expected, drivers are needed.
6. Using Zadig, I generated a WinUSB driver for each of my sub-devices. Drivers installed successfully.
7. Using the winusb_test.exe utility, I started sending/receiving data. On the first interface - everything is fine. What I send to OUT point 0x01 is returned to the host through IN point 0x81. The second interface is only half working. The data sent via OUT-point 0x02 gets to the controller, I accept it and send it back through IN-point 0x82, but... nothing is sent. The winusb_test.exe utility does not accept anything. The "Device Monitoring Studio" sniffer does not see anything either.
   In the step-by-step controller debugging mode, I noticed this:
   directly sending a data byte to the IN point is carried out in the `USB_WritePacket` function via this instruction:

```
USBx_DFIFO((uint32_t)ch_ep_num) = __UNALIGNED_UINT32_READ(pSrc);
```

The `USBx_DFIFO` macro, by the endpoint number ch_ep_num, gives a pointer to the corresponding fifo buffer (for point 1, this will be the address 0x50002000). And a byte is written to this address. At this moment, on the host computer, I see the arrival of data.
When writing a byte (for example, 0x31) for a normal point 1, the buffer state becomes:
[image]

For problem point 2, when writing the same byte (0x31), the buffer state for some reason becomes like this:
[image]

And nothing comes to the host...
Everything seems to be fine in the OTG_FS_DIEPCTLx register for point 2, it is enabled (EPENA bit=1), buffer number TXFNUM=2, maximum packet size MPSIZ=64.

I would be grateful for advice on what I missed during initialization and where to dig further.